# Pythonic wrapper strategies

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, python-3.x

I want to write a wrapper around a REST API, and I been having trouble with a couple of issues:

1. Should objects be opaque, concrete (all properties defined), or a mix
2. Are there existing libraries that can help with #1
3. Should a wrapper be async if it making web calls?  Is this possible if you need py 2/3 support?

Are there any good websites related to doing this task?

Comment: What are the requirements your wrapper is supposed to meet? That's the one that's going to answer #1. How are your users going to use this wrapper? That's going to answer #3.

Comment: I would definitely recommend async for number 3. Not sure I completely understand number 1.

Comment: @akshatmahajan - the wrapper is going to be used for scripting purposes to manage the site's content.  The API I'm wrapping is Complicated and large, so this definitely will be a fascade type layer to make it hopefully more logical.

Comment: @cricket_007 is there an async library I should use for PY2/3 support?